# Tableau IF THEN Statement - Change Measure Based on Date

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, aggregation

I have a Tableau report that calculates employee productivity each month. The report calculates the minutes per document based on document type. The minutes per document standards are being changed effective 11/1/2020.

I have added a new column to the previous Doc Standards table - the columns are Doc Type, Min Per Document (which contains the standards prior to 11/1/2020) and Current Min Per Document (contains the new standards >=11/1/2020).

Currently the report has a calculated field for Earned Hours with the formula:

```
SUM([Min Per Document])/60
```

I want to update this formula based on the Report Date so that prior to 11/1/2020 the calculation uses Min Per Document and after 11/1/2020 uses Current Min Per Document. I have the following formula:

```
IF ATTR([Report Date])<'11/01/2020' THEN SUM([Min Per Document]/60)
ELSE SUM([Current Min Per Document]/60)
END
```

I receive "The calculation is valid.", however, when I look at the data, the Current Min Per Document (the new standards that are effective 11/1/2020 forward) value shows in the view even for Report Dates <11/1/2020.

I'm unsure of how to fix the formula to calculate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot/sample data is desired.

Please try this

```
Sum(
If [date] <= #2020-01-11# then [field1] else [field2] end
)/60
```

The idea is to use If then else end statement outside aggregation and apply aggregation thereafter.

Comment: This worked and the correct value is now computing. Thank you!

Comment: If this helped, please upvote and accept it, as normally desired on stack overflow.